# Astroturfing on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, advertising, abuse, astroturfing

I just wanted to make sure you guys are aware this happens sometimes before I delete this user.

[What is Astroturfing?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing)

> Astroturfing is a word in English describing ... advertising, or public relations campaigns seeking to create the impression of being spontaneous "grassroots" behavior, hence the reference to the artificial grass, AstroTurf.

User in question:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/96878/tom-lo

(Edit: sorry, Marc spoilt the fun by accident; not much to look at on this account now....)

Take a look.

Comment: No links though...interesting.  I wanna know what this LiquidTest is now.

Comment: I mean, he/she didn't post any links.  Which is interesting.

Comment: Maybe he just really, really likes LiquidTest.

Comment: There was a link in the first answer he posted.

Comment: @shog Right, of course I didn't look at that one...

Comment: Mind if I ask you how did you spot him?

Comment: @jjnguy: well, it was the most boring of the lot. Except for the two where he didn't mention LT at all...

Comment: Thanks Jeff! With your help I just discovered a great new product called LiquidTest which I now use in my day to day development!

Comment: Maybe it sounded like a joke, but I'd really like to know what raised you a flag about this particular user in the thousands of registered SO users.

Comment: (too many moderators spoil the broth; many links no longer there; see below)

Comment: If there was only one "user", it's not astroturfing!  Astroturfing would be if the guy hired a bunch of his union buddies to create SO accounts and post/vote-up the message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since I plan to delete this user, some sample "answers" for permanent reference.

Answer

> We got tired of how badly Selenium handled XPaths, and the fact that XPaths were the main cause of us having to maintain scripts every time there was a minor layout change from the coders. We successfully trialled and then purchased several licences of a product called LiquidTest. We no longer have to combine multiple tools like Firebug and Python scripts together to create a test that will actually run.
>
> The teams finishing projects with Selenium are jealous of the teams on the newer projects using LiquidTest, and they can't wait to get involved or be on the next new project. That's a good sign in my books

Answer

> I have found XPaths to be more trouble than they are worth. They're ok if you're not changing the pages your testing, but if you're not changing them, why not spend less effort testing them.
>
> When my CTO factored in the cost of the man hours editing the Selenium scripts to work every few builds, we realised that it provided us with a poor return on investment. We've spent some R&D time hunting alternative tools. The latest is a trial version of a a tool called LiquidTest. It seems less brittle so far, using other references to objects before resorting to XPaths. It runs in Eclipse, records tests through the browser UI and can write JUnit, Ruby, C#, etc. so all the Java coders here picked it up almost immediately. So far so good.

Answer

> The problem with Selenium RC as far as I can tell is that it was created by a third party. Even Jason Huggins has trouble making RC work - http://clearspace.openqa.org/message/48380
>
> We trialled and purchased a product called LiquidTest that lives up to their claim that it makes test record and replay as easy as it was meant to be. It handles dragging splitters in our ExtJS framework pages, and replay works just fine without hacking or adding python.

There are a few answers that could be construed as valid, but the overall pattern is very strong and consistent -- astroturfing.

Comment: I wonder if there are smarter austroturfers. Even to spot this one I would have to combine a few answers to detect unusual pattern reliably.

Comment: Oh, I see. There were much more posts.

Comment: yes there were about ~10 like the above, this is just a sampling

Answer (score 12):

Of course misrepresenting your affiliation is unacceptable, but what if each of the posts had a full disclosure at the bottom? Is that still disallowed?

On another note, how can you tell the difference between an enthusiastic user and genuine astroturfing? In this case it was pretty obvious because the user had little content otherwise, but I'm sure that there are some users on the site with as many or more answers that boil down to "use JQuery" in response to a JavaScript question. Is it OK because it's free/open source? Where's the line?

Comment: I'm sort of an Eclipse evangelist, but I post other things too.  I feel it is pretty easy to tell this person's motives, at least in this case.

Comment: I'd be pretty annoyed if someone did nothing beyond visit questions asking for help with Prototype, posting answers dissing that library and recommending jQuery... There's a fine line between astroturfing and just being a jerk.

Comment: There is a pretty obvious line. - The user's motives.

Comment: Well, unless you can find out who he really is, that's kinda hard to see...

Comment: But would you find it okay if someone promoted something(without "dissing" something else) while giving full disclosure of their affiliations with the product/library/whatever they promote? That's the question I find very relevant.

Comment: Yeah.  We let John Resig and Miguel de Icaza and the fiddler guy hang out.  As a matter of fact we encourage it.

Comment: "In this case it was pretty obvious" -- it always is

Comment: Oh, and Joel.  They all have products that they fairly clearly represent.  However, they are a very valuable resource to teh community.

Comment: It can be hard to determine intent from a post, since *successful* astroturfing appears to be legitimate. There are a few cases, like this one, where it's blatant (and I would say poor) astroturfing, but I suspect there are many more that fly under the radar.

Comment: (I don't have any examples, and I realize that it's circular logic to say that I don't have any examples because they're *that good*, and they wouldn't be *that good* if I could identify them. I guess that makes this more of a hypothetical example, but you do have to recognize there is at least *theoretical* grey area here)

Comment: @Kyle Your whole comment was just a parenthetical...fabulous!

Comment: @kyle I *theoretically* agree with you. In theory.

Comment: As Kyle said, a post with a disclaimer seems ok. Once you are affiliated with a particular product/library/etc, you should probably disclaim that fact. The recommendation however should still push the product based on its technical merits and not based on ones affiliation.

Answer (score 7):

I have a gold badge in one of my employer's trademarks. Should I delete all my posts?

Seriously, my employer has an anti-astroturf policy. I feel the need to insert the occasional disclosure statement. I guess it's a matter of common sense rather than something that can be automated. Though perhaps I could insert a TM symbol every time I mention an affected trademark, such as JavaScript<sup>TM</sup>.

Comment: So, you work on Java?

Comment: My user info might give it away.

Comment: Or it could be lying to me...

Comment: My new goal is to pass you in 'Questions tagged Java' ranking.  No hard feelings...But I need a new goal now that I hit 10k.

Comment: Excellent. There's +1 for you.

Comment: Well, don't make it too easy now `:P` Thanks!

Comment: Yup, gotta make you work for it. :)

Answer (score 7):

With regards to the accounts that only exist to astroturf... I know you're not a huge fan, but I wonder whether a "hellban" approach would work. Note that I'm not suggesting this approach for the "exist to aggravate" accounts, since they tend to be throwaway accounts; but 'turfers tend to keep their account.

The problem with deleting the account is that we know very well (from experience) that these accounts tend to see more resurrections than the Vatican film festival. At least with a hellban we know where they are. Presumably only mods and the user would see them.

The system would also probably need to throw them random up/down votes, just to keep things interesting. Not sure what to do if they attempt to edit somebody else's post... perhaps just tiddles?

[image: Turf wars]

Comment: *Not sure what to do if they attempt to edit somebody else's post...* I don't think an astroturfer would get enough reputation to get edit previleges... but maybe I'm just optimistic.

Answer (score 3):

I would say there's nothing wrong with promoting a product if that's what the question was about, e.g. "is there any better alternative to Selenium?". But if the question is "how do I do X in Selenium?", referring to other products is irrelevant. In this case, half the time his posts were half relevant, the other half they were irrelevant advertising that did not answer the question.

Comment: The problem is when somebody exists on the site **purely** to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I have a few examples of what I did on Super User:

- https://superuser.com/questions/4412/dvd-library-on-windows-media-center-extender
- [Is it possible to have Media Center show details for my movie files?](https://superuser.com/questions/2303/is-it-possible-to-have-media-center-show-details-for-my-movie-files)
- https://superuser.com/questions/2605/what-is-the-best-media-center-software

It's a slippery slope, some rules that are important to live by:

- Don't bad mouth the competition, even if it sucks.
- Don't answer every question with "just use my software"
- Always disclose your affiliation

I find it incredibly difficult to deal with this issue.

Comment: ASTROTURFER!!!! BUUURRN HIM!

Comment: @Jeff - OK, account deleted as per request... that is what you intended? no? Oops ;-p

Comment: Isn't why there is 'Caveat' or 'bias-warning' ?

Answer (score 2):

Ooopsssiiieee... Jeff: I didn't look at MSO first, but was looking at this user separately due to some spam flags. I too noticed the behaviour, and deleted all but the 3 posts that didn't do any of this. So there isn't much left to look at on this account now.

Sorry to spoil the fun, guys.

Jeff: if you want to do a public show-and-tell again, perhaps add a moderator annotation to the account so that other moderators don't delete it out from under you ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Awww... Poor Selenium. They just couldn't match the inherent awesomeness of FluidTest!

Comment: LiquidTest.  If you are gonna subtly advertise, do it right.

Comment: Dammit, FluidTest offered me major $$$ to subtly diss both Selenium and LT - now you've screwed up my twofer!

Comment: You don't know for sure who the guy (or gal or bot) works for.

Answer (score 1):

They should really know better than to try that on a site by programmers for programmers.

We're more likely to notice when something isn't quite right. We also like exploring inconsistencies. Which makes it significantly more difficult to sneak something behind our backs.

If they really wanted people to use their stuff, there is this little thing called **advertisements**.

Comment: But if they have a product for programmers, advertising on a site for programmers makes the most sense.

Comment: Well, i guess they could advertise on a site for CTOs...

Comment: @shog9: but then it should be migrated to scheduleoverrun.com

Comment: @tkadlubo: this thread is currently second for the search scheduleoverrun.com Somebody gotta register that site!

Answer (score 0):

When discussing or linking to your own or affiliated products, a caveat and full disclosure is always appropriate, if not required.

For example, I like the tool [Balsalmiq Mockups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balsamiq#Overview).

Caveat: I have no affiliation with Balsalmiq, and I'm not nearly as fond of ponies as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22164/thetxi), but I love my new iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

I really don't see the problem. Sure, those answers are annyoing and when I read them I get a little angry. I sympathize when the owner of stackoverflow gets even more angry.

But usually, we do rely on voting. Don't we? If this liquid test stuff is any good and better than selenium (which I kind of doubt, but that's not the issue here), his answers will be voted up because they really are helpful. And if he's advertizing crappy stuff, he'll be downvoted pretty soon.

Comment: I agree. This negativity towards astroturfing is driving me back to ExpertsExchange. 

ExpertsExchange.com - Where experts come together (tm).

Comment: *Check it out*.