# People Advertising their Services/Companies

Tags: discussion, advertising, spam

I have just taken the liberty to [edit out](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1222647/list) some too obnoxious advertising, and I was just wondering what the general consensus is about people advertising their own companies or services?

My common sense tells me that this is acceptable if the answer really answers the question (as opposed to copy/pasting the marketing flyer or a generic "Maybe our product would do this" link), but the question is how good the answer is given the fact that the person is clearly biased.

For example, someone gave [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260129/silverlight-protecting-content-inside-a-network-drm/1150630#1150630) on one of my questions which is self-advertising, but IMHO not unwanted Spam because it is one solution, although other people might think differently.

Answer (score 6):

Blatant advertising is generally frowned upon. If they are advertising their own company as an answer to a particular question and it makes sense, I as a moderator would see it as acceptable, but that doesn't say anything for whether or not the community would react with the same acceptance.

If it is unwanted spam, immediately flag as spam or flag for moderator attention and it can be taken care of in a jiffy.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case the answer should have been flagged as spam. The promotion of products has been discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10174/using-so-sf-su-to-promote-your-products) before.