# What is the Stack Overflow policy on plugging your own product when relevant?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, advertising, self-promotion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it appropriate to mention my product in a StackOverflow answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13295/is-it-appropriate-to-mention-my-product-in-a-stackoverflow-answer)
>   [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)

I openly admit it in the answer that I am a developer working on the (free as in free beer, closed) software and almost always point to alternatives as well.

Sometimes, the best way to do things is to just use our software and I mention it.  I am asking this question largely because a regular user in the field accused me of marketing my company's software. I admit that some of my colleagues have been over-exuberant and have been sent to the penalty box, but I have always tried to keep it clean.

But it would be nice to have a look at stackoverflow policy on this and see the dos and don'ts. If there is none, what would you prefer, as user / contributor, in this regard ?

Comment: lol - three separate proposed duplicates... yep.. I think this topic has been covered ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. Its been a long day and I didn't scroll down all the way. :(

Comment: No worries!  Just be careful not to annoy anyone when you promote yourself - sometimes it is not received well if you do not fully disclose your affiliation...

Comment: This was my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10169295/535516. I think affiliation was pretty obvious. The first comment, from a user that I respect, just angered me a little..

Comment: I guess some people just don't like the idea of "self-promotion" at all... You can't please everyone all the time.

Comment: So, what exactly are you complaining about here then? Some random user left a snarky comment on your answer? Sorry, we can't solve that problem. If it's really an offensive or inappropriate comment, flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: It wasn't a complaint, more of a clarification because I haven't been in this situation before. That _random_ user is one of the most active users on cuda tag, so I wanted to know if I was pissing off the community at large.

Answer (score 1):

What did you feel was inadequate about [the FAQ entry dedicated to precisely this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)?

> #### May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) for details. We also offer [free community promotion ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) for open source projects and non-profit organizations.