# PHPKode.com links spamming Stack Overflow

Tags: support, spam

Spam users are injecting bad content linking to phpkode.com.

From a cursory search for "PHPKode":

- [Exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324129/ckeditor-question/4599947#4599947)
- [Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436852/how-to-choose-the-right-php-framework-for-web-development) (Posing as a question, "PHP Framework" [Massive Google bombing attempt](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Which+PHP+framework+is+the+right+one+I+am+seeking+for%22))
- [Exhibit C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289594/i-would-like-to-look-for-a-php-imap-based-client-with-following-requirements) (both contributions by this user point to PHPKode)
- [Exhibit D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567759/php-domdocument-error-handling-problem/4567832#4567832)
- [Exhibit E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445965/php-imap-install-problem) (Google-Bomb fake question, again)
- [Exhibit F](https://serverfault.com/questions/206462/a-php-imap-based-client-with-following-requirements) fake question on Serverfault

This behaviour does not seem to be limited to Stack Overflow. [Usenet example](https://groups.google.com/group/de.comp.lang.php.misc/browse_thread/thread/f7b991fd7508ffbe?hl=de)

I say this calls for a link blacklisting.

Comment: Ouch. Wish I had more spam flags. The questions are particularly insidious - SO users tend to go easy on them.

Comment: Might as well just link to [a search for PHPKode](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpkode). I think maybe... *one*... of the results *isn't* spam...

Comment: OK, limited out my spam flags.

Comment: I can't tell for all examples. But I'd also like to know the general stance on commercial links. I've yesterday replaced a (repeated) link to RegexBuddy (which is still a good tip!) with our very [own list of free alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world). User was not pleased but cool with it. But is there a general guidance on such matters?

Comment: @mario AFAIK, commercial links in general are fine. See e.g. here for extended discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55914

Comment: @mario: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion - if you have a connection, disclose it. If your answer (or question) exists for no purpose other than linking to your product/site, then you'll probably still die in a fire.

Comment: @Shog9: Okay, thanks. So obviously spamvertizing the own blog or products is the major offence. But what about linking to spam-ladden sites you are not associated with? @Pekka: The "IMAP" examples are clear cases. And it also seems evident from PHPKode looking Facebook/SEO-centric. Only in the second exhibit it seemed an explainative reference link.

Comment: @mario Kudos for assuming good faith, but: http://www.google.de/#sclient=psy&hl=de&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=%22Which+PHP+framework+is+the+right+one+I+am+seeking+for%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=9518358c6ae80f89 these are really evil bastards

Comment: @Pekka: Oouh! Ok. I concede your research was conclusive.

Comment: @mario: again, the disclosure requirement is only there to help sincere users avoid the appearance of astroturfing. Repeatedly posting off-topic links will get you into trouble regardless of whether or not you're affiliated with what you're linking to.

Comment: This is depressing. ++ link blacklist.

Comment: I'm maxed out now, too, though I did manage to nuke a question into orbit in the process. Some of the stuff found in that search link is okay, IMO.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ok, I added

`\bphpkode\b`

to the universal blacklist